# Is the derivation of the ratio R a Corollary to the Angle Bisector Theorem?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I observed that a ratio, R, can be computed from the lengths of sides in an angle ACB.  Refer to the diagram below.

The calculable known distances b and c in the diagram can be used to develop a ratio, R = c/(b+c) which is applied to delta x and y of points A and B (and added to coordinates of point A) to render the absolute coordinates of point M.  Point M is the intersection of a ray along the angle bisector and the segment AB.

My question: Is this ratio R simply a corollary derivable from the Angle Bisector Theorem or is it different?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uBsL.jpg)

Comment: That is the angle bisector theorem -- the angle bisector of an angle divides the opposite side according to the side lengths $AM:MB::CA:CB$.  From there you get $c/d=b/e$ which rearranges to your $c/(c+b)=d/(d+e)$.

Comment: Thanks! Can this property be called a corollary or is it simply a straightforward application of the Theorem?

Comment: I am writing a technical paper in the field of terrain modeling and I "discovered" this relation and thought it might be related to the Theorem, but could not get from c/d = b/e to c / (c+b) = d/(d+e).  Would you mind expanding those steps and let me have your name, so that I can credit you for it?  Thanks again.

Comment: It is straightforward application of the theorem and the [algebraic rules for manipulating ratios](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookV/defV14.html).  $c/d=b/e$ gives $c/b=d/e$ and so $c/(c+b)=d/(d+e)$.